# Init.d script causing boot hang

Tags: linux, debian, init, raspberry-pi, init.d

I successfully installed a script to automatically launch in /etc/init.d on my new Raspberry Pi.

Unfortunately, it is a node.js app that never returns, and therefore hangs the device during boot (this is on Debian). Yes, I'm an idiot.

Is there a secret handshake I can do during boot to prevent it from running my init.d script so I can get to login and a shell to fix it?

Comment: Doesn't booting single-user mode do this?

Comment: http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-sag-en-4/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this is this, and I warn you, it involves Windows.

I mounted the flash card on my PC and edited "cmdline" and added "ro 1" to the end of the kernel config.   This only allows boot to proceed thru runlevel 1 and then drops you into root shell after a prompt.

NOTE:  Windows 8 can read the kernel config file unmodified - no special drivers needed.